# SQL - Retrieve data where MAX number < number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset where I need to find the 'Class' a user was logged onto when they had a break. The 'Class' for the break should be the same 'Class' as the first login event preceding the break.
Happy to have the data in an extra column just not sure how to go about it.

```
---------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE Test (     
       [Rowid] INT NOT NULL
      ,[Agent_Name] VARCHAR NOT NULL
      ,[Type Login_Break] VARCHAR NOT NULL
      ,[Class] INT NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (Rowid)
);

INSERT INTO Test 
    ([Rowid], [Agent_Name], [Type Login_Break],[Class]) 
VALUES 
    (7276541,'TrevorT','Login',162),
    (7276993,'TrevorT','Break',0),
    (7277421,'TrevorT','Break',0),
    (7278660,'TrevorT','Login',106),
    (7278754,'TrevorT','Login',162),
    (7279485,'TrevorT','Break',0),
    (7280372,'TrevorT','Login',69),
    (7280984,'TrevorT','Break',0),
    (7281135,'TrevorT','Login',162),
    (7282310,'TrevorT','Login',162),
    (7283716,'TrevorT','Break',0)
---------------------------------------------
```

My initial thought was to try a CTE where MAX(RowID) < (RowID) however am running into dead ends each time.

#### Original Output:

[image]

#### Required Output:

[image]

Comment: In the example screenshot, just manually looking at it, what would be result you would expect to be returned by a query?

Comment: You should give us your DB schema, example input, desired output, what you have tried so far.

Comment: Where the Class = 0 I'd like it to return the Class of the preceding login event, in the screenshot rows 2 & 3 would be 162 & line 8 would be 69.
Let me know if I'm not being overly clear.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: @TrevorT go ahead and edit your question and type out the result you want. You can even type out the result in Excel and paste a screenshot - whatever is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks @zedfoxus - have updated with original/required screenshots

Comment: Nice work @TrevorT. I have added an answer, example and explanation to the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you can try something like this:

```
with data as (
    select *, 
        case 
        when class = 0 then
          (
            select max(rowid) from test
            where class > 0 and rowid < a.rowid
          )
        else null
        end as newrowid
    from test a
)
select
    data.rowid, data.agent_name, data.[type login_break],
    case when data.class = 0 then test.class else data.class end as class
from data
left join test on data.newrowid = test.rowid;
```

**Result**

```
rowid   agent_name  type login_break    class
7276541 TrevorT     Login               162
7276993 TrevorT     Break               162
7277421 TrevorT     Break               162
7278660 TrevorT     Login               106
7278754 TrevorT     Login               162
7279485 TrevorT     Break               162
7280372 TrevorT     Login               69
7280984 TrevorT     Break               69
7281135 TrevorT     Login               162
7282310 TrevorT     Login               162
7283716 TrevorT     Break               162
```

Example: https://rextester.com/QITJ76405

**Explanation**

- Create a dummy dataset using test
- In this dummy dataset, add a column for when class = 0
- This column will be the maximum ID of previous rows
- That way, you'll get info about the previous class prior to the break
- Get all the data from this dummy dataset and join it with the original where newrowid matches original rowid
- When dummy dataset has class 0, substitute it with class from original

Comment: Thanks so much, that's working perfectly. Really appreciate your time and expertise, I've been banging my head against the wall on this one off and on the last week or so!!

Answer (score 2):

This will work on SQL Server, syntax used is SQL standard

SQL Server fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9733051365513941f5057dc38c0b6356

Postgres fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uxVcYPsw4tFCjpJtX3VrCh/0

```sql
with a as 
(
  select
      *, 
      sum(case when type_login_break = 'Login' then 1 end) 
      over(order by row_id) as login_group
  from test
)
select 
    row_id, agent_name, type_login_break, 
    class, 
    sum(class) over(partition by login_group order by row_id)
from a;
```

Output:

```
| row_id  | agent_name | type_login_break | class | sum |
| ------- | ---------- | ---------------- | ----- | --- |
| 7276541 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162 |
| 7276993 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162 |
| 7277421 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162 |
| 7278660 | TrevorT    | Login            | 106   | 106 |
| 7278754 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162 |
| 7279485 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162 |
| 7280372 | TrevorT    | Login            | 69    | 69  |
| 7280984 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 69  |
| 7281135 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162 |
| 7282310 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162 |
| 7283716 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162 |
```

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution!

Comment: @zedfoxus This is neater: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860178/sql-retrieve-data-where-max-number-number/55860804#55860804 Unfortunately, SQL Server has no user-defined aggregate yet

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBuen - that's awesome too, unfortunately, I think I can only mark one response as an answer.

Comment: Really appreciate your response, there's more than one way to skin this cat!!

Answer (score 2):

Can do it in single pass if SQL Server has [user-defined aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587556/sum-until-threshold-value-reached-and-then-reset-the-counter/55588103#55588103):

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vXymxPPj3Ngmqoa9DqFc7S/0

```sql
select *, 
    sum_with_reset(class, type_login_break = 'Login') over(order by row_id)
from test
```

Output:

```
| row_id  | agent_name | type_login_break | class | sum_with_reset |
| ------- | ---------- | ---------------- | ----- | -------------- |
| 7276541 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162            |
| 7276993 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162            |
| 7277421 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162            |
| 7278660 | TrevorT    | Login            | 106   | 106            |
| 7278754 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162            |
| 7279485 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162            |
| 7280372 | TrevorT    | Login            | 69    | 69             |
| 7280984 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 69             |
| 7281135 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162            |
| 7282310 | TrevorT    | Login            | 162   | 162            |
| 7283716 | TrevorT    | Break            | 0     | 162            |
```

sum_with_reset definition:

```sql
create or replace function sum_reset_accum(
    _accumulated numeric, _current numeric, reset boolean
)
returns numeric as
$$
    select case when reset then
        _current
    else
        _current + _accumulated
    end    
$$ language sql;


create aggregate sum_with_reset(numeric, boolean)
(
    sfunc = sum_reset_accum,
    stype = numeric,
    initcond = 0
);
```

Comment: It took me a couple minutes to read docs to understand what was going on; this is very elegant!

Answer (score 0):

No need for CTE or rank  , just need simple select with case statement:

```
 select  
         Rowid, 
         agent_name, 
case [type login_break] when 'login' then RowID else
         (select top 1 RowID from test where RowID < t.Rowid and BreakClass='Break' order by 
         rowid desc) end as Login_Break_Class
    from test t
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bit hard without the full table schema, but I would suggest creating a CTE using the RANK() or DENSE_RANK() functions. Then something like:

```
SELECT * FROM cte1 WHERE R = 1;
```

Where R = the new column using the Rank function.