# Is there a way to display INNER JOIN entries in the order they're entered in the clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner when it comes to MySQL and I've taken it upon myself to create a type of translating service like google translate. The problem is the querys are not being displayed the way I enter them, instead they seem to be ordered by the ID column.

I've tried (with my limited knowledge) looking into different ways of creating relations etc. to display the equivelent words in the different languages. For now I've landed on trying to use the INNER JOIN clause to display and "structure" the sentences.

```
SELECT swedish.word,
       german.word,
       german.swear,
       swedish.swear,
       swedish.id
FROM   swedish
       INNER JOIN german
               ON swedish.id = german.id
WHERE  swedish.word = "Hej"
        OR swedish.word = "Mitt"
        OR swedish.word = "Namn"
        OR swedish.word = "Är";
```

This will display the swedish words alongside the german words, aka create sentences but it will now diplay in the order i typed them in, instead it will sort in by the ID column, which mixes the words around. Is there any solution to this?

Here's and image of the results, ordered by the ID:

[image]

I've thought about using ORDER BY and some sort of temporary value and then order it by that but then I'm not sure about how to implement and auto increment that value for only the selected entries/rows.

I'm using OR statements to enable more than one entry in the same result, as parentheses (seen in other tutorials) gave me syntax errors.

Also, if there is a better way of going about this please let me know!

EDIT: I would want to clarify that I am aware that this is not a sustainable solution for creating a transaltion service, I simply thought this would be an interesting way to understand a bit more about how you can connect and work with different tables etc.

Comment: Please share some sample data from these tables and your desired results. The order of the columns in the record will be based on your `SELECT` clause. The order of the records being output will be based on your `ORDER BY` which is absent here, so it's however Mysql retrieved the records (arbitrary). But without some sample data and desired results it's difficult to discern what you mean by `order`. I suspect your meaning has more to do with your `JOIN` and the result set returned from that `JOIN`, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: In a relational database management system, rows represent unordered sets, so the only way of guaranteeing an order, is by specifying one within an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Some weird 'rollbacking' going on here

Comment: *"so it's however Postgres retrieved the records (arbitrary)."* @JNevill what does PostgreSQL has to do with it? As the question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Good catch! I was just reading a postgres question before this. That's what!. I updated my comment to reflect OP's RDBMS.

Comment: @JNevill I've added an image with the results as well as some issues I've stumbled upon with ORDER BY. Thank you for your input!

Comment: That makes more sense to me now. You are sending in (via your `OR` WHERE predicates) a sentence, and asking this query to send back the same order in both languages. This will be difficult to achieve in a single query since you can't reasonably send in, via sql, the desired order of the output. You might consider writing these input values (and their order) into a temp table, and then executing sql where you join to that temp table, ordering by the order in that temp table. If you are on mysql 8.0 then perhaps a CTE with a UNION may suffice as well.

Comment: @JNevill "This will be difficult to achieve in a single query since you can't reasonably send in, via sql, the desired order of the output." You can, there are ways to solve that ordering in query alone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903352/is-there-a-way-to-display-inner-join-entries-in-the-order-theyre-entered-in-the/55904550#55904550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you mean, but try this way:

```
   SELECT swedish.word,
           german.word,
           german.swear,
           swedish.swear,
           swedish.id
    FROM   swedish
           INNER JOIN german
                   ON swedish.id = german.id
    WHERE  swedish.word = "Hej"
            OR swedish.word = "Mitt"
            OR swedish.word = "Namn"
            OR swedish.word = "Är"
    ORDER BY field(swedish.word,"Hej","Mitt","Namn","Är");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(swedish.word, 'Hej,Mitt,Namn,Är');
```

Comment: True, though it may be worth noting that this is MySQL only; probably better to focus on standard SQL approaches when learning SQL as a skill

Comment: @CaiusJard Care to offer standard SQL solution for this? Standard SQL sometimes comes short in terms of performance and/or code elegance  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587556/sum-until-threshold-value-reached-and-then-reset-the-counter/55588652#55588652 The accepted answer(mine) taps the RDBMS-specific functionality

Comment: Some MySQL-ism are just neat and elegant. +1'd this

Comment: There is a standard SQL version in forpas's answer. This is  a more concise alternative.

Comment: @MichaelBuen - this has got `DRY` issues too. I'm not proposing that they use `FIND_IN_SET` for the `WHERE` clause as it won't be sargable. They still need the `IN` - this is just to apply ordering to their current query

Comment: @MartinSmith I overlooked the IN requirement :) I deleted my comment before I even see your reply. Ah yes, the SARGability is an issue with `FIND_IN_SET`

Answer (score 1):

> Also, if there is a better way of going about this please let me know!

It isn’t the databases job to do this, it’s the front end’s job

If you have the sentence;

> Hej Mitt Namn Ar Caius

Then the front end should do something like this (pseudocode):

```
string newsentence = “”
foreach(word in sentence.split(‘ ‘))
  newsentence = newsentence + “ “ + dblookup(word)
```

(You can assume dblookup is a helper method that takes a single [swedish] word and returns the equivalent single [german] word)

The order is preserved because you perform database lookups in order as you traverse the sentence. You don’t try to send all the words to the db, and force order the results so you can just concat them back into a sentence, you look up one word at a time. If you have the same word twice in a sentence, all the approaches here (in other answers - at the time of writing this answer) will break; a sentence of “hej mitt hej” will come back ordered as “hallo hallo meine” because you can’t ask the db to order hej as both first and third, all the “hej” will order to be first

There isn’t much to be gained by submitting multiple words for translation, some minor performance benefit maybe but it would be trivial. If you were engineering this solution for performance you could have your dblookup method cache a few hundred thousand most recently requested words, but don’t bang your head on the wall of trying to submit an entire sentence to the db in “or or or” style and preserving the order; it’s so complicated to do so and for no practical benefit

As a brief aside, this isn’t how languages work either, though I appreciate that this is the very early stages and you may just be indertaking this for a learning exercise - you cannot make a translator software by literally translating each word by word individually

Comment: Alright, thank you! Yes, this is very early on and I intially started this in order to explore and learn about relations in databases and dont really plan on taking it anywhere big :)

Comment: Even if you want to do the ordering on the client I wouldn't do a separate database lookup for each word

Comment: @martinsmith why not? The time it saves in Dev simplicity far outweighs the runtime speed gained at the expense of the complexity of requesting 5 words at a time and then sorting them out in the client. Cache things if you want but the OP has already said this is a learning exercise, not something that has to outperform google for a million simultaneous requests. Go for the simple solution, not the perfect one, test, and address performance issues once you know there actually is one

Comment: `a sentence of “hej mitt hej” will come back ordered as “hallo hallo meine” because you can’t ask the db to order hej as both first and third, all the “hej” will order to be first` You can ask the db to do that. I think you're just underestimating the capabilities of modern dbs though. See here "hej mitt hej" will come back ordered as "hallo meine hallo" (not "hallo hallo meine") with db functionality alone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903352/is-there-a-way-to-display-inner-join-entries-in-the-order-theyre-entered-in-the/55904550#55904550. I won't refute your ideas though

Comment: At the time of writing Gordon hadn't posted (I assume thats who you refer to) and he has since posted a technique for preserving the word order but it's arguably quite an ugly unmaintainable kludge, it's NOT what/how databases should be used(for). *"Just because you can, doesn't mean you should"*. This whole thing is an academic/learning exercise and nearly everyone seems to have overlooked that part in their desperation to show off their mad SQL skills. At its core this whole problem is a very simple lookup and should NOT have anywhere near this level of complexity associated with it..

Comment: Hence the disclaimer: I won't refuse your other ideas. It's not mad SQL skills, I don't find anything special about it, it's just pure relational, a simple lookup, which every dev worth their salt should at least know. There's no complexity associated with doing it in the database, granted that the database is capable of expressing things in concise manner, e.g., with Postgres, you just need to pass the array from the client side to the db, this won't entail "unmaintainable kludge", which could happen with MySQL's UNION as it will require dynamic query

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a subquery with prioritization:

```
SELECT s.word, g.word, g.swear, s.swear, s.id
FROM swedish s JOIN
     (SELECT 'Hej' as word, 1 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Mitt' as word, 2 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Namn' as word, 3 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Är' as word, 4 as ord
     ) w
     ON s.word = w.word JOIN
     german g
     ON s.id = g.id
ORDER BY w.ord;
```

The advantage of this approach over other approaches is that the list of words is only included once.  This makes it easier to update and prevents errors when writing thew query.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your way to sort the rows with CASE in ORDER BY:

```
SELECT 
  swedish.word, german.word, german.swear, swedish.swear, swedish.id 
FROM swedish INNER JOIN german 
ON swedish.id = german.id 
WHERE swedish.word IN ('Hej', 'Mitt', 'Namn', 'Är')
ORDER BY CASE swedish.word
  WHEN 'Hej' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Mitt' THEN 2
  WHEN 'Namn' THEN 3
  WHEN 'Är' THEN 4
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some fundamental problems with your question:

> I've taken it upon myself to create a type of translating service like google translate.

Automated translation is **hard**, and can't be solved just by word-to-word database lookups (especially if you're "a beginner when it comes to MySQL"). Languages have lots of complicated grammar rules, and you can't translate a sentence just by translating it word-for-word. Take a look at [this article](https://blog.statsbot.co/machine-learning-translation-96f0ed8f19e4): You'd really have to get into something like machine learning, rather than (just) database development.

If you want experience with automated translation, you might want to take a look at the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).

Another problem is that you seem to have a separate table/entity for each language. This is problematic: As the number of languages grows, the number of tables will increase. To translate from `Language A` to `Language B`, you'll have to know which tables to use, which will likely involve dynamic SQL. It would be far better to properly normalize your data. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Words
(
    word_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    universal_name VARCHAR(255) -- the "universal" way to refer to a word (e.g. you could store the Esperanto version).
);

INSERT INTO Words
(word_id, universal_name) 
VALUES 
(1, 'hello');

CREATE TABLE word_translations
(
    word_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Words(word_id), 
    language VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    word_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO word_translations
(word_id, language, word_name)
VALUES
(1, 'en', 'hello'),
(1, 'es', 'hola');
```

But again, this won't really solve the problem of translation, since word-for-word translations aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Gordon Linoff, just automating the numbering of the order of filter list:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (fruit varchar(10), sweetness int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl
    (fruit, sweetness)
VALUES
    ('apple', 7),
    ('banana', 6),
    ('papaya', 4),
    ('grape', 2),
    ('watermelon', 3)
;
```

Query, just including Postgres for its expressiveness :)

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3fa48/3

```sql
with a as
(
   select * 
   from unnest(array['banana','grape','apple','banana']) 
   with ordinality as x(f,i)
)
select tbl.*,'',a.i 
from tbl
join a on tbl.fruit = a.f
order by a.i;
```

Output:

```
|  fruit | sweetness | ?column? | i |
|--------|-----------|----------|---|
| banana |         6 |          | 1 |
|  grape |         2 |          | 2 |
|  apple |         7 |          | 3 |
| banana |         6 |          | 4 |
```

Query for MySQL:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86b0d9/4

```sql
select tbl.*, '', a.i 
from tbl
join (
    select @i := @i + 1 as i, x.f
    from
    (
      select 'banana' as f
      union all
      select 'grape'
      union all
      select 'apple'
      union all
      select 'banana'
    ) as x
    cross join (select @i := 0) y    
) a on tbl.fruit = a.f
order by a.i;
```

Output:

```
|  fruit | sweetness |  | i |
|--------|-----------|--|---|
| banana |         6 |  | 1 |
|  grape |         2 |  | 2 |
|  apple |         7 |  | 3 |
| banana |         6 |  | 4 |
```